# Style issues with Telerik components

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I got a DLL that contains only stylized components for padronized use, using simple Telerik components as a base.

The issue here is that i can use all of the components normally in my applications, but only some of these seems to respond to the changes i made, while the others just look like the Telerik components.

What can i be doing wrong?

The modifications in one of the Telerik components (Button):

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:gi="clr-namespace:GI_ComponentesWPF">

<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/GI_ComponentesWPF;component/Themes/GIBase.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

<!--a brush that represents the outer border color of the button, when it is in Normal state.-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlOuterBorder_Normal" Color="#FFb9b9b9"/>

<!--a brush that represents the background color of the button, when it is in Normal state.-->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ControlBackground_Normal" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFC8C8" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFF6464" Offset="0.333"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFF1432" Offset="1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFF9696" Offset="0.171"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<!--a brush that represents the foreground color of the button, when it is in Normal state.-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlForeground_Normal " Color="Black"/>


<!--a brush that represents the background color of the button, when the mouse is over it.-->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ControlBackground_MouseOver" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDCC8C8" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDC6464" Offset="0.333"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFC81428" Offset="1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDC9696" Offset="0.171"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>


<!--a brush that represents the inner border color of the button, when the mouse is over it.-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlInnerBorder_MouseOver" Color="Transparent"/>

<!--a brush that represents the outer border color of the button, when it is pressed.-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlOuterBorder_Pressed" Color="#ffcdcdcd"/>

<!--a brush that represents the background color of the button, when it is pressed.-->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ControlBackground_Pressed" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFBE6E6E" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFBE5A5A" Offset="0.333"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF960A1E" Offset="1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFBE6E6E" Offset="0.171"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<!--a brush that represents the inner border color of the button, when it is pressed.-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlInnerBorder_Pressed" Color="Transparent"/>


<Style x:Key="RadButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type gi:GIBotaoComumTeste}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF848484"/>
    <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFC8C8" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF6464" Offset="0.333"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF1432" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFF9696" Offset="0.171"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type gi:GIBotaoComumTeste}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="0,0,-185.167,-164.584">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterMouseOverBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CommonStatesWrapper"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterMouseOverBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterMouseOverBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF282828"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF5F5F5F" Offset="1"/>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ControlBackground_MouseOver">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFBE6E6E" Offset="0"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFBE5A5A" Offset="0.333"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF960A1E" Offset="1"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFBE6E6E" Offset="0.171"/>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="InnerMouseOverBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF3C3232"/>
                                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF6E6464" Offset="0.126"/>
                                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="disabledBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Content"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="BackgroundVisibility">
                            <VisualState x:Name="BackgroundIsHidden">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="OuterBorder"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="disabledBorder"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="BackgroundIsVisible"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStatesGroup">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual">
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.15" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}">
                        <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding InnerCornerRadius}"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="OuterMouseOverBorder" BorderBrush="#FFFFC92B" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <Border x:Name="InnerMouseOverBorder" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding InnerCornerRadius}">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDCC8C8" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDC6464" Offset="0.333"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFC81428" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDC9696" Offset="0.171"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="disabledBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="#FFE0E0E0" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="CommonStatesWrapper">
                        <Border x:Name="FocusVisual" BorderBrush="#FFFFC92B" BorderThickness="1" Background="Transparent" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Opacity="0" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Border x:Name="FocusInnerVisual" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding InnerCornerRadius}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: You probably just need to [provide a new `ControlTemplate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084(v=vs.110).aspx) for them.

Comment: Telerik controls can be a pain in the *** when you go to style them, I'd take @Sheridan 's advice on looking at the controltemplates as I've often found things hardset in them or theme.manager crap in there not playing nice. Personally when I re-do a telerik control I do the whole thing instead of just trying to pick out colors because you'll end up cutting out a lot of garbage.